# Get the Json Data in ios

Tags: ios, arrays, json, nsstring, nsmutabledictionary

I am getting the some doctor's data from JSON URL. That data is showing a single doctor location for some doctors and showing multiple locations for some doctors.

I need to display this data.

```
 "id":"135","speciality":"Allergy","type":"P",   
   "doc_name":"Patrick M. Ambrosio, D.O., F.A.C.A.A.I.",   
   "doc_profile_url":"Patrick-M-Ambrosio",    "doc_offices":[
          {
              "office_id":17,
              "office_name":"Old Bridge",
              "office_url":"Old-Bridge",
              "state":"New Jersey",
              "state_short":"NJ",
              "city":"Old-Bridge",
              "lat":"40.3975",
              "lon":"-74.3298",
              "office_combined_name":"Old Bridge,New Jersey,NJ"
          },
          {
              "office_id":7,
              "office_name":"Woodbridge",
              "office_url":"Woodbridge",
              "state":"New Jersey",
              "state_short":"NJ",
              "city":"Iselin",
              "lat":"40.555",
              "lon":"-74.3151",
              "office_combined_name":"Woodbridge,New Jersey,NJ"
          }    ]
          }, {
          "id":"2",    "speciality":"Allergy",    "type":"P",    "doc_name":"Ricardo Arayata, M.D., F.A.C.A.A.I.",   
   "doc_profile_url":"ricardo-arayata-md",    "doc_offices":[
          {
              "office_id":22,
              "office_name":"Purchase",
              "office_url":"Purchase",
              "state":"New York",
              "state_short":"NY",
              "city":"Purchase",
              "lat":"41.0099",
              "lon":"-73.6959",
              "office_combined_name":"Purchase,New York,NY"
          },
          {
              "office_id":15,
              "office_name":"New Rochelle",
              "office_url":"New-Rochelle",
              "state":"New York",
              "state_short":"NY",
              "city":"New-Rochelle",
              "lat":"40.9158",
              "lon":"-73.7864",
              "office_combined_name":"New Rochelle,New York,NY"
          }    ]
          }, {
          "id":"3",    "speciality":"ENT",    "type":"P",    "doc_name":"Anna Aronzon, M.D.",   
   "doc_profile_url":"anna-aronzon-md",    "doc_offices":[
          {
              "office_id":27,
              "office_name":"Wall Street",
              "office_url":"Wall-Street",
              "state":"New York",
              "state_short":"NY",
              "city":"New-York",
              "lat":"40.7096",
              "lon":"-74.0104",
              "office_combined_name":"Wall Street,New York,NY"
          }    ]
          }, {
          "id":"4",    "speciality":"ENT",    "type":"P",    "doc_name":"Jonathan Aviv, M.D., F.A.C.S.",   
   "doc_profile_url":"jonathan-aviv-md",    "doc_offices":[
          {
              "office_id":23,
              "office_name":"Sleepy Hollow",
              "office_url":"Sleepy-Hollow",
              "state":"New York",
              "state_short":"NY",
              "city":"Sleepy-Hollow",
              "lat":"41.0802",
              "lon":"-73.8572",
              "office_combined_name":"Sleepy Hollow,New York,NY"
          },
          {
              "office_id":6,
              "office_name":"East Side",
              "office_url":"East-Side",
              "state":"New York",
              "state_short":"NY",
              "city":"New-York",
              "lat":"40.7768",
              "lon":"-73.9541",
              "office_combined_name":"East Side,New York,NY"
          }    ]
          }, {
          "id":"163",    "speciality":"ENT",    "type":"P",    "doc_name":"Andrew Azer, M.D.",   
   "doc_profile_url":"andrew-azer-md",    "doc_offices":[
          {
              "office_id":17,
              "office_name":"Old Bridge",
              "office_url":"Old-Bridge",
              "state":"New Jersey",
              "state_short":"NJ",
              "city":"Old-Bridge",
              "lat":"40.3975",
              "lon":"-74.3298",
              "office_combined_name":"Old Bridge,New Jersey,NJ"
          },
          {
              "office_id":7,
              "office_name":"Woodbridge",
              "office_url":"Woodbridge",
              "state":"New Jersey",
              "state_short":"NJ",
              "city":"Iselin",
              "lat":"40.555",
              "lon":"-74.3151",
              "office_combined_name":"Woodbridge,New Jersey,NJ"
          }    ]
```

I am giving that code also once please check it out this:

```
    - offC = [[[rr  objectForKey:@"doc_offices"]
           objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"office_name"];  
 NSString *docOfficeID
           = [[[rr objectForKey:@"doc_offices"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"office_id"];
```

Comment: what error are u getting?? and are u storing the json in an array or not?

Comment: Yes I have store the data in array. But I want to write for loop for checking the condition

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution :

```
        NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
        NSMutableArray *arrDoctorInfo  = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonParsingError];
        for (NSMutableDictionary *data in arrDoctorInfo) {

            NSMutableArray *arrOffice = [data valueForKey:@"doc_offices"];
            NSString *strID = [data valueForKey:@"ID"];
            .
            .
            NSString *strdoc_profile_url = [data valueForKey:@"doc_profile_url"];
            for (NSMutableDictionary *dictDoffice in arrOffice) {
                NSString *strdictDoffice = [dictDoffice valueForKey:@"office_id"];
                .
                .
                NSString *stroffice_combined_name = [dictDoffice valueForKey:@"office_combined_name"];
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why everyone suggest third-party frameworks? iOS have native JSON serialization tool: `NSJSONSerialization`. This is extremely easy to use. For example:

```
dispatch_queue_t fetchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("nameOfYourQ", NULL); //here i create dispatch for connection (do not block UI!)
dispatch_async(fetchQueue, ^{ // block to fetch and parse
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourlink"]]; // NSData - connection for JSON
    id arrayOrDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil]; // parse NSData object to Dictionaries and Arrays.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [yourTableView reloadData]; // reload your view on main thread.
    });
});
```

This is very simple example. What i like to do is use `NSURLConnectionDelegate` for download data and then in delegate method use `NSJSONSerialization` for parse data.

Wait, in your JSON structure you have more than one `doc_offices` keys. So i think you really have (to get `office_id`)
array - dictionary - dictionary - array.

So:

```
NSNumber *docOfficeID = [[[[rr objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"doc_offices"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"office_id"];
```

And this is not a `NSString`. This is `NSNumber`